# Azure CLI 2 - Doesn't show any app service plans

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I'm trying out the new [Azure CLI 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/)

I can see subs, and things like redis caches no problem.

But I can't work out why I can't see my app service plans - of which I have many:

`az appservice plan list` - Empty json object returned

`az appservice plan list -g MyGroupName` - Also nada

`az appservice web list` - Also nada

Can anyone shed some light on this? I'm using version 2.0.2 on macOS.

Comment: wrong subscription?

Comment: Nope, I've only got the one sub

Comment: Could you list your plans on Azure Portal? `az appservice plan list` could list existing plans.

Comment: Yeah, everything works fine on the portal. The only thing I notice is that on the portal, I've got 2 "directories" listed for my account - one is my personal email and one belongs to an active directory I hooked up. Maybe I need to change the "directory"?

Comment: Do you check the result `az account list --output table`?

Comment: I have the same problem---`azure appserviceplan list --resource-group MyResourceGroup` works but none of the `az appservice plan` commands return anything.  Did you resolve it in chat?

Comment: @mikebridge I've just come back to it now - still not working for me :(

Comment: Updated to latest version (2.0.12 I think) and it's all working now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated to latest version (2.0.12) and it's all working now!

Answer (score 2):

```
az appservice plan list
```

This cmdlet could list existing plans. Please ensure you have select the correct subscription.

Get a list of all subscriptions in your account.

```
az account list --output table
```

Set the default.

```
az account set --subscription "My Demos"
```

More information please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/manage-azure-subscriptions-azure-cli).

Comment: Thanks. I see just one account when I `az account list`. I set my subscription to that just to make sure: `az account set...`, but `az appservice plan list` still returns nothing

Comment: The result is an empty json object, as though I didn't have any app service plans. I've got about 15 of them, that I can see in the portal.

Comment: yes - I tried both my personal azure login, and the AD account that's connected. Both accounts allow me to see *some* things, e.g. sql databases, redis databases, but no app service plans or websites

Comment: If possible, could you try this on Windows VM or Linux VM? I don't have Mac, I test on Linux, `az appservice plan list` could list all my plans.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141347/discussion-between-walter-msft-and-matt-roberts).